# remove double quotes from string and convert into symbol

Tags: ruby, string

This is very simple scenario..

I tried to get all the username and id as hash from the object user.

```
user = User.all
data = {}
User.map do |u|
   data[u.name.to_sym] = u.id
end

# data will be.. 
data[:"test"] = 1 ..

But, I need like this data[:test] = 1
```

I want to remove the double quotes from the string (begin and end) and convert into symbol.. 
or Is there any direct way to convert the model object into hash value what I expected?

I know, there are lot of way (regx or string functions) to remove the double quotes from the string. But, I am expecting very optimized and simple solution.

Comment: `:"test" == :test`; do you really need to remove the quotes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you opposed to just using the strings?

Comment: @JanDvorak You are correct..And I knew it.. :-) But, I'm thinking why double quotes..

Comment: Notice that `a = :"test" => :test` (as @Jan mentioned), `"'test'".to_sym => :""test""`, `'"test"'.to_sym => :"\"test\""` and `"test kit".to_sym => :"test kit"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have name like this *"name@bond"*
`"name@bond".to_sym #=>output :"name@bond"`

then you must want to remove @ ' " .. any other special characters

```
"name@bond".parameterize.underscore.to_sym #=> :name_bond
"name@bond".parameterize #=> "name-bond"
"name-bond".underscore #=> "name_bond"
"name_bond".to_sym #=> :name_bond
```

Here's a reference [ruby-doc symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Symbol.html)

Comment: Take a note parameterize is in ActiveSupport gem (included by Rails). Questions isn't tagged with rails so it worth to point it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'test'.parameterize.underscore.to_sym
```

or

```
'test'.to_sym
```