# How to create a key hash without quotes

Tags: ruby, literals

I'm trying to create a header to my api like this:

```
header = {:Content-Type => "application/json"}
```

I have a problem with the key that contains a dash. If I use `:"Content-Type"` or `"Content-Type".to_sym`, the result is a key like this:

```
"Content-Type".to_sym # => :"Content-Type"
```

I found some people saying that I can use `to_sym.inspect` to create a symbol without quotes, but it didn't work.

```
"Content-Type".to_sym.inspect # => ":\"Content-Type\""
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove double quotes from string and convert into symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174487/remove-double-quotes-from-string-and-convert-into-symbol)

Comment: Did you try to define symbol in console like, `:Cat-food` ?

Comment: Huh? Just use `{"Content-Type" => "application/json"}`. Why bother with symbols at all here?

Comment: It feels to me like you already figured out that `{ :"Content-Type" => "application/json" }` would work. What is your question? What do you try to achieve and why?

Comment: @spickermann: I am 99.99%  sure that the underlying api that this header hash is being prepared for, it will handle string keys just as well.

Comment: I am sure OP thought `:Content-Type` is valid symbol :|

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I think so too. I just wonder if the OP wants to use symbols and when the OP already figured out how to create symbols what the issue and the question is?

Comment: OP mistakenly believes the symbol contains `"` because its representation does.

Comment: @cremno: ah, good guess!

Comment: `{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` (using `:` instead of `=>`) will also work if you really want to create a symbol. Most likely you don't and should just do `{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }`.

Comment: You can't create `{:Content-Type => "application/json"}` because there is no such thing. That expression is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This is an classic example of value vs value representation.

Let me provide you with some examples:

```
'"'
#=> "\""
```

```
'
'
#=> "\n"
```

```
'a-b'.to_sym
#=> :"a-b"
```

All the above blocks have the same in common. The output is not a literal but should be interpreted into the context.

- `"\""` is not a string containing a backslash and a double-quote, but a string containing a single double-quote (`\"` represents a double-quote in double quoted string context).
- `"\n"` is not a string containing a backslash and an "n", but a string containing a single newline character (`\n` represents a newline in double quoted string context).
- `:"a-b"` is not a symbol containing `"a-b"`, but a symbol containing `a-b` (`:"..."` represents a symbol that can't be parsed without quotes).

This can be seen when we print out the values.

```
puts "\""
# "
#=> nil
```

```
puts "\n"
#
# => nil
```

```
puts :"a-b"
# a-b
#=> nil
```

As you can see in the above code block, the quotes are not actually part of the symbol. They are just for the symbol representation.

---

If the symbol actually contained the quotes the representation would look like:

```
a = '"a-b"'.to_sym
#=> :"\"a-b\""

puts a
# "a-b"
#=> nil
```